# How can I make my dropdown menu blocks center aligned under the parent item block?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have been trying to edit my dropdown menu so that the sub-items are centered beneath the parent items. I finally achieved the centering only to find that every time I hovered over a parent item to reveal the drop down menu, the rest of the menu fell to the bottom of the dropdown menu.

Here is the link to the sample, it has all the coding on one side. Thank you in advance for your help! I am just starting out with CSS and HTML and no matter how many videos and tutorials I watch and read, I just can't seem to get it right :(

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FEEMWLIFAMAO

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `vertical-align: top;` to your `.dropdown` css like so:

**CSS**

```
.dropdown {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Also on a separate note I would remove the width on `.dropdown-content` and instead put the width on `.dropdown` to make sure they are both the same width and no wacky horizontal position changes on hover. Another solution is to make the dropdowns position: absolute; and position them relative to the links. But off-topic :)

Answer (score 0):

You could set the dropdown-content's position to `absolute`. To center the dropdowns, you have to position them relative to the parent's width. This would look something like this in your `.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {`:

```
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: calc((100% - 150px)/2);
width: 150px;
text-align: center;
```

To explain the positioning a little further:
`100%` refers to your parent's width. Take the difference of this and the `150px` you specified as the `width` of your dropdown-content. Since you want your box centered below the menu button, this difference has to be divided between the left and right side, hence you have a padding of `(100% - 150px) / 2` on each side.

Answer (score 0):

Both the **parent element** and the **child element** you are trying to position **relatively** to said parent have the `position: relative` property applied to their styling, which is inappropriate for the result you seem to be trying to achieve.

Have a read on the [css position property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) and its values.

**Explanation**: your child element is being **displayed** as a `block`, which by definition occupies a horizontal space on its own, while being **positioned** `relative` to its parent element, therefore pushing the rest of the latter adjacent navigation elements under said parent element.

**Solution**: The navigation effect you seem to be trying to achieve is generally done by positioning the subnavigation **absolutely**, relative to the navigation element that makes it appear on hover: its parent. This way said subnavigation does not affect the positioning of the elements where it is hierarchically placed inside the **html** code.

**CSS**:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    //To position the element:
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```